# CSS styles are overriding the styles of embedded HTML

Tags: html, css, github

I'm embedding a GitHub gist onto a page. However, all the styles from the page are overriding the styles of the embedded header and text. See the snippet for an example:

```css
h1 { color: blue; }
p { color: red; }
```

```html
<h1>An example header!</h1>
<p>here's some text</p>
<script src="https://gist.github.com/dochoffiday/333a22e937f7503cd770ed70a429df23.js"></script>
```

In the above example, I *don't* want the header to turn blue or the text to turn red in the embedded gist. What can I do here so my styles don't mess up the ones imported by the gist?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to go through that minified CSS to figure this out. You need to clean it up an add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The gist gets injected in your DOM, so naturally it inherits the document's styles. You can "scope" your CSS classes, but this is not exactly the easiest way to go if you have a lot of content.

By wrapping your non-gist content in a block (`<div class="content">` below), you can ensure the classes are only applied to descendants of `.content`.

```css
.content h1 { color: blue; }
.content p { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h1>An example header!</h1>
    <p>here's some text</p>
</div>
<script src="https://gist.github.com/dochoffiday/333a22e937f7503cd770ed70a429df23.js"></script>
```

Sadly you can't just use `:not(.gist) h1` or `:not(.gist) p` because technically, all the elements between the injected `.gist` block and its `h1`/`p` aren't classed with `.gist` so the selector evaluates to true.